# Shell mode does not do autocompletion for loaded functions

Tags: completion, shell-mode

When running in a terminal, the shell does auto-completion *even* for loaded functions:

```
$ check-<tab><tab>
check-bios-nx           check-dirty             check-language-support  check-manifest
```

And `check-dirty` is a function:

```
» type check-dirty 
check-dirty is a function
check-dirty () 
{ 
    is-older-than 24 ${REPO_LIST} || refresh-repo-list;
    cat ${REPO_LIST} | while read dir; do
        cd $dir;
        test -z "$(git status --porcelain)" || printf "%-50s : dirty\n" "$dir";
        cd - > /dev/null;
    done
}
```

But in `emacs`, the `completions` buffer show me a different list:

```
Click on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
check-bios-nx
check-language-support
check-manifest
```

The function is also loaded in the `emacs` shell buffer. In fact, the whole environment is exactly the same as the environment in the shell in the terminal (except minor things like `TERM`)

Why is my loaded function not being shown in auto-completion in emacs? Is there a "bash compatibility mode" for the shell mode?

It is this small inconsistencies in behavior which prevent me for going full `emacs`, and I keep using other tools (in this case `bash` in a terminal) for different tasks.

Answer (score 2):

The completion function for `shell-mode` is `shell--command-completion-data`. It searches for filenames in the current directory and executable files on your path. It does not consider functions. You could write your own replacement function, possibly using the shell command `declare -F` to dynamically collect the list of defined functions. However, there's nothing available 'out of the box' to do this for you.